# How long does GHCi remember data once loaded?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I wrote `baby.hs` with a single line of code:

```
doubleMe x = x * 2
```

After saving the file, I loaded it in (terminal) GHCi using `:l baby`. 
It was interpreted and loaded correctly.

I tested it using 
`doubleMe 10`
Which gave me the result 
`20`.

After that I deleted the Haskell code i.e the `doubleMe x = x * 2`. The file `baby.hs` was blank. Saved the file.

I loaded it again. It was interpreted and loaded correctly.
I tested it using 
`doubleMe 25` 
which gave me the result 
`50`.

**My questions:**

1. How long does GHCi remember the previously loaded functions/data?
2. How can I flush this memory?

Comment: type `Prelude> :l`. Also, I can't reproduce your error. After reloading the blanked-out file, definition was not available anymore.

Comment: Same as Will Ness here. Can you do it again, just to check? Also, which operating system, and which version of ghc?

Comment: Are you sure you were changing the same file and not a different one? In particular, check if you might have been changing a file with a hidden extension like `baby.hs.txt` if you're on Windows.

Comment: Maybe I was editing a different file and was loading old file from a different directory.